# How to get rid of unnecessary space above text HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this text element inside of a div. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3u1x.png) You can see there is some blank space between the text and the border. I was wondering how to get rid of it. Here is the code

```css
.fancy-blue-box {
  
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #3F7CAC;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #004E89;
  opacity: 1;
  float: top;
  color: aqua; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

body {
  text-align: center; 
  
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: aqua;
  margin: auto;
}

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>

    <div class="fancy-blue-box" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
      <h4>
        Text
      </h4>
      <p>
        More text
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Right click on the element you want to fix and click inspect. 2. Untick each box until you see that it is the margin or the padding you want to change

Comment: The `h4` has a default `margin-top` applied via the user agent stylesheet, so overwrite that with 0.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help! The second one worked for me

Comment: .fancy-blue-box has a 10px margin decalred... also the The h4 has a default margin-top, as pointed out by @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```css
   .fancy-blue-box {
      background-color: #3F7CAC;
      border-style: ridge;
      border-width: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-color: #004E89;
      opacity: 1;
      float: top;
      color: aqua; 
      display: inline-block;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      padding: 0px;
      line-height: 0px;
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: aqua;
      margin: auto;
    }

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
      <body>

        <div class="fancy-blue-box" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
          <h4>
            Text
          </h4>
          <p>
            More text
          </p>
        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the following padding and the text will appear at the edges of the box, remove the margin if space on the outside of the box becomes a problem...

```
.fancy-blue-box {
  
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #3F7CAC;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #004E89;
  opacity: 1;
  float: top;
  color: aqua; 
  display: inline-block;

  margin: 10px;   <---- This one!
  padding: 10px;  <---- This one!

  line-height: 0px;
}
```